# How to disable roundoff error tracking in arbitrary precision arithmetic?

Tags: numerics, arbitrary-precision, error-tracking

In my calculations I need some larger precision. But due to the fact that I iteratively refine the results to compensate for rounding errors accumulated in previous iteration, *Mathematica*'s arbitraty precision arithmetic's roundoff error tracker kills all the results by converting them to effective zero — I can't even divide by such result without getting divide-by-zero error.

In my application a completely wrong intermediate result is much better (and is actually expected) than no result as I get with error tracking. I've tried using `SetPrecision[]` at some places in calculation, but in some cases I have to do it in *many* places, which makes the code unreadable.

So, is there any way to just get additional precision, but without tracking roundoff errors?

Comment: I can't picture a case in which your desired behavior would be desirable. Could you provide a minimal example of your specific application?

Comment: So you just want to use a fixed and pre-determined number of digits in all calculations, and you want to avoid truncating the number of digits after each operation?  And you need more than 15 digits?

Comment: @Szabolcs yes. Basically what e.g. x87's `tbyte` or IEEE 754's binary128 formats would provide, but potentially with even more precision and range.

Comment: How important is performance?  I am looking at the ComputerArithmetic package for the first time and it's quite interesting.  It lets you define a number format and "arithmetic" with specific rules, then do calculations with it.  I would expect it to be slow but I haven't tested how slow exactly.

Comment: @Szabolcs well if its performance would be twice as slow as usual arbitrary precision, it'd be OK. If tenfold, then not so good.

Comment: I don't know then.  I'm curious if there will be a good answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs there is now a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few reasonable ways. I'll illustrate with an example of Newton iterations for square roots, take from [this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Apr/msg00066.html)

```
r[x_, n_] := x - (x^2 - n)/(2*x)
x = 1.0`20;
two = 2.0`20;
```

First we run it with the usual arithmetic.

```
Table[x = r[x, two], {30}]

(* Out[680]= {1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.414213562373095049, 1.414213562373095049, 1.414213562373095049, \
1.41421356237309505, 1.41421356237309505, 1.41421356237309505, \
1.4142135623730950, 1.4142135623730950, 1.4142135623730950, \
1.4142135623730950, 1.414213562373095, 1.414213562373095, \
1.414213562373095, 1.41421356237310, 1.41421356237310, \
1.41421356237310, 1.4142135623731, 1.4142135623731, 1.4142135623731, \
1.4142135623731, 1.414213562373, 1.414213562373, 1.414213562373, \
1.41421356237, 1.41421356237, 1.41421356237, 1.4142135624, \
1.4142135624} *)
```

We can force fixed precision as below. I'll just show a few iterations.

```
x = 1.0`20; NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate[
 Table[x = r[x, two], {10}], 20]

(* Out[681]= {1.5000000000000000000, 1.4166666666666666667, \
1.4142156862745098039, 1.4142135623746899106, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488} *)
```

Alternatively, use `SetPrecision` explicitly to reset upward.

```
x = 1.0`20;
Table[x = SetPrecision[r[x, two], 20], {10}]

(* Out[683]= {1.5000000000000000000, 1.4166666666666666667, \
1.4142156862745098039, 1.4142135623746899106, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488} *)
```

Last is to temporarily set min and max precisions to be equal. `Block` is good for this type of localized assignment.

```
x = 1.0`20;
Block[{$MinPrecision = 20, $MaxPrecision = 20}, 
 Table[x = r[x, two], {10}]]

(* Out[685]= {1.5000000000000000000, 1.4166666666666666667, \
1.4142156862745098039, 1.4142135623746899106, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488, \
1.4142135623730950488, 1.4142135623730950488} *)
```

Comment: This is great! A caveat with `SetPrecision` is that if the result has zero digits of precision, it'll give very precise zero instead of what you'd get with `FixedPrecisionEvaluate`: see e.g. `SetPrecision[((2\`2^2\`1)^2\`1)^2\`1, 10]`.

Comment: Right. `SetPrecision` as used above is intentionally subverting the precision tracking system, so  it should be done only in situations where one knows it is appropriate.